# delete one-to-one relationship in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently developing an application using flask and I'm having a big problem to delete items in an one-to-one relationship. I have the following structure in my models:

```
class User(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   user_id = db.Column(db.String(8), primary_key = True)
   password = db.Column(db.String(26))

class Student(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'student'
   user_id = Column(db.String(8), ForeignKey('user.user_id'), primary_key = True)
   user = db.relationship('User')

class Professor(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'professor'
   user_id = Column(db.String(8), ForeignKey('user.user_id'), primary_key = True)
   user = db.relationship('User')
```

What I want to do is delete the Student or the Professor if I delete the user. I have tried to test it using the code below, however, when I check my database, the student and professor are still there and my tests don't pass. I tried to include the cascade parameter when I set the relationship but it doesn't work. I have found in the internet to use this parameter: *single_parent=True*, but it also doesn't work.

```
user1 = User(user_id='user1234',password='alsdjwe1')
user2 = User(user_id='user2345',password='asfr5421')
student1 = Student(user = user1)
professor1 = Professor(user = user2)
db.session.delete(user1)
db.session.delete(user2)
```

I'd be glad if somebody can help me with this.

Thank you very much,

Thiago.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cascade` argument in your relationships.

```
class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'student'
    user_id = Column(db.String(8), ForeignKey('user.user_id'), primary_key = True)
    user = db.relationship('User', cascade='delete')

class Professor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'professor'
    user_id = Column(db.String(8), ForeignKey('user.user_id'), primary_key = True)
    user = db.relationship('User', cascade='delete')
```

You might want to look into [delete-orphan](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#delete-orphan) if your use case needs it.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it doesn't work by itself. I had to insert a delete-orphan method in the User class for making it work. It removes the Student and the Professor, however, it doesn't remove the relation of students with another class called Courses, to whom Student is linked in a Many-to-Many relationship. So, the table Students_Courses in my database remains with the id of the student and the course, even if I delete the student. I don't know if it is sufficient information, but if you don't understand what I explained I edit and insert the courses class as well. Thanks :)