# Why does my child model persist in the database when associated parent is deleted?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having a very rough time getting used to flask and how it works with Sqlalchemy. What I want is to have a one to one relationship cascade for deletion between a child element and its parent.

For my case I have an `Employee` class that has one `Photo` associated with it. This code below shows how I have it wired up:

```
class Photo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'photos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    image = db.Column(db.String(200))
    image_storage_type = db.Column(db.String(255), default='')
    image_storage_bucket_name = db.Column(db.String(255), default='')

    def __init__(self, image='', image_storage_type='', image_storage_bucket_name=''):
        self.image = image
        self.image_storage_type = image_storage_type
        self.image_storage_bucket_name = image_storage_bucket_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Photo %r>' % self.image

class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    photo_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Photo.id))
    photo = db.relationship("Photo", backref=db.backref('employee', cascade='delete', uselist=False))
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    email = db.Column(db.String(200))
    department = db.Column(db.String(200))

    def __init__(self, name='', title='', email='', department='', photo=Photo()):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.email = email
        self.department = department
        self.photo = photo

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.name
```

I specified the `cascade='delete'` on Employee so the cascade should work yet it fails. The association is there and I am able to query but the deletion fails to execute. I followed the SQLalchemy documentation and this stack overflow question that I found `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970594/delete-one-to-one-relationship-in-flask`

I am confused why this isn't working. Could someone assist please?

Comment: "but the deletion fails to execute" How? Does it throw an error? If it does, what is the error message?

Comment: The deletion only occurrs for the Employee but not the Photo.
`employee = ('Name','Title','Email','Department',Photo('employee.jpg'))`

`db.session.add(employee)`

`db.commit()`

'db.session.delete(employee)`

`db.session.commit()`

The photo object will persist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed to change my code from this:

```
photo = db.relationship("Photo", backref=db.backref('employee', cascade='delete', uselist=False))
```

into this:

```
 photo = db.relationship("Photo", backref='employee', cascade='all, delete', uselist=False)
```